# jQuery bind to submit causing problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, submit, bind

I show a form using jQuery Fancybox -- in the form, the user has the option to edit the record or delete the record.

The JS config for this popup is as follows:

```
$('tr.record').click(function() {
    var record_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var link = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/expenses/expenses_edit/' + record_id;
    $.fancybox({
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'ajax',
        'href': link,
        'onClosed': function() {
            parent.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
    $.bind("submit", function() {

        $.fancybox.showActivity();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: $(this).serializeArray(),
            success: function(data) {
                $.fancybox(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This works perfectly when the user changes his data and clicks save, as below:

```
<form>
    <button>
        <span>
            Save
        </span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Next I opened a new form for the delete button

```
<form>
    <button onclick="confirmDeleteRecord();">
        <span>
            Delete
        </span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Which onClick runs this:

```
function confirmDeleteRecord() {
    var agree = confirm("This expense will be removed and you can't undo this action. Are you sure you want to remove this record?");
    if (agree) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I click on 'Cancel' in the browser modal confirmation, the form is still submitted and the record is deleted.

I suspect this has to do with the `bind` to `submit` -- anyone know how to fix this issue? 'Cancel' should just close the browser modal.

Thanks for helping, much appreciated.

Comment: Does the form submission button have a unique ID or a class that you can pass to jQuery a la `$("#submitButton").bind('click', function() {});`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the button HTML to as follows(use return confirmDeleteRecord();):

```
<button onclick="return confirmDeleteRecord();">         
   <span>             Delete         </span>     
</button>
```

Edit:

Better way is to attach a click event handler to the delete button in an unobstrusive way.
You can try this as an alternative:

```
<button id="deleteBtn">         
   <span>             Delete         </span>     
</button> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $("#deleteBtn").click(confirmDeleteRecord);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I think a better solution would be to remove the `onclick` assignment from the HTML entirely, and do the click binding with jQuery.  Unobtrusive JS and all...

Comment: @cybernate -- thanks that does exactly what I wanted - sweet and simple!

Comment: @Ender: I agree with you on that...will update the post with alternative.

Comment: @cybernate, @ender --- awesome, using the unobtrusive version -- i guess points go to @cybernate? -- let me know -- thanks to everyone for helping

Comment: It's about the helping, not the points...well ok, it's sortof about the points :)

Comment: IF you're using jQuery you're much better off using it without the end <script> stuff from a consistency point of view.

Comment: @ShaneC: I didn't get you. Can u pls elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

You must bind the submit handler TO something.  This is your problem line:

```
$.bind("submit", function() {
```

You'll need to select the form that is being submitted and bind a submit handler to the form.  So, for example, if your form has id `myForm`, it should say something like this:

```
$('#myForm').bind("submit", function() {
```

Or even better, use the shortcut call:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
```

For your button, remove `onclick="confirmDeleteRecord();`, and give it a class or id instead:

```
<button id="btnDelete">
    <span>Delete</span>
</button>
```

And finally, add a click handler assignment to your jQuery:

```
$('#btnDelete').click(confirmDeleteRecord);
```

For the sake of tidiness, you could also simplify your confirm function like so:

```
function confirmDeleteRecord() {
    return confirm("This expense will be removed and you can't undo this action. Are you sure you want to remove this record?");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your bind will bind to every submit.  You need to provide an id or class selector for each submit.  For instance:

```
$('#classname').submit(function() { // your code here }
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Actually, OP's bind will do nothing, because `$.bind()` is not a function in jQuery.  It should be `$('something').bind()`